# Probability of lognormally distributed $\mathrm{SO_2}$ concentrations

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> The probability of the $\mathrm{SO_2}$ concentration over a forest is lognormally distributed with mean $1.9$ and standard deviation $0.9$. What is the probability that the concentration lies between $5$ and $10$?

I have tried to solve this the normal way by just standardizing the lognormal distribution:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
P\left( 5 < Y < 10 \right)
&=& P\left( \ln{5} <\ln{Y} < \ln{10} \right) \\
&=& P\left( \ln{Y} < \ln{10}) - P(\ln{Y} < \ln{5} \right) \\
&=& P\left( Z < \frac{\ln{10} - 1.9}{0.9}\right) - P\left(Z < \frac{\ln{5} - 1.9}{0.9} \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
with $Z$ being standard normally distributed. This equals approximately
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
P\left( Z < 0.44 \right) - P\left( Z < -0.32 \right)
&=& P\left( Z < 0.44 \right) - P\left( Z > 0.32 \right) \\
&=& P\left( Z < 0.44 \right) - \left[1 - P\left( Z < 0.32 \right)\right] \;,
\end{eqnarray}
$$
and then using a standard normal table this should be equal to
$$
P\left( 5 < Y < 10 \right) = 0.670 - (1 - 0.626) = 0.296
$$

But this is not the right answer. It should be $0.0087$ according to my book.
So, where did I go wrong?